# Distinguish between inserted and updated records when using the EFCore.BulkExtensions library method BulkInertOrUpdate

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, efcore.bulkextensions

I have to fill in `CreationTime` and `LatestUpdate` columns in my SQL Server database tables. `CreationTime` must be `DateTime.Now` at the time of insert, instead `LatestUpdate` must be updated to `DateTime.Now` every time the record is updated. I have to update in bulk a lot of records, so I want to use the the `EFCore.BulkExtensions` library method [BulkInsertOrUpdate](https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions/).
I managed to fill in `CreationTime` once forever by putting it by default to the value `DateTime.Now` and by using bulk configuration `PropertiesToExcludeOnUpdate` on it.
However, I can't manage to fill in `LatestUpdate` in the correct way.

I have tried to use bulk configuration `PropertiesToExcludeOnCompare` after being filled in with `DateTime.Now`. But this option always updates my `LatestUpdate` field to Now, whether other columns have been updated or not. I can't understand  what this option is for. It seems to work always at the same way.
In the documentation:

> By adding a column name to the `PropertiesToExcludeOnCompare`, will allow it to be inserted and updated but will not update the row if any of the other columns in that row did not change.

It seems a contradiction in terms. How is a row marked as updated or not? Is there a way to discover, so that I can set `latestUpdate` column correctly?
In conclusion:

```cs
BulkInsertOrUpdate(Entities, new BulkConfig()
{

    PropertiesToExcludeOnCompare = new List<string>()
    {
        nameof(BaseEntity.LatestUpdate)
    },
    PropertiesToExcludeOnUpdate = new List<string>()
    {
        nameof(BaseEntity.CreationTime)
    }

});
```

works correctly for `CreationTime`, but not for `LatestUpdate`

Comment: "But this option always updates my LatestUpdate field to Now, whether other columns have been updated or not" are you calling `BulkInsertOrUpdate` with records that already exist and don't need update?

Comment: Yes. In my test case is the case. The requirement is that I don't know in advance if a record should be inserted or updated. That's why I use BulkInsertoOrUpdate. It is an import from excel taht can consist in records that previously exists on db or should be newly inserted. I have LatestUpdate column to discriminate it and trigger correctly subsequent trasformations on db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have tried to use bulk configuration PropertiesToExcludeOnCompare
> after being filled in with DateTime.Now. But this option always
> updates my LatestUpdate field to Now, whether other columns have been
> updated or not.

Make sure for the **entities** that already exist and you aren't going to do any updates on aren't initializing a new `DateTime` value on `CreationTime`  when you call method `BulkInsertOrUpdate`.

In the `PropertiesToExcludeOnCompare` list, `CreationTime` was not added that means if you initialize it i.e
`public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;`
(value is now different from what's in the database) and proceed to call `BulkInsertOrUpdate` all fields for that record will be updated in the database except ofcourse `CreationTime` since it was excluded with `PropertiesToExcludeOnUpdate`.

If this is the case solution then would be to add it to the `PropertiesToExcludeOnCompare` list in order to avoid doing comparison on `CreationTime` between entity and record existing in database.